# How to infer generic type from function parameter in Kotlin?

Tags: kotlin, generics

I have a base enum like this

```
enum MyEnum<T> {
    val initialValue: T
    val minValue: T
    val maxValue: T 
}
```

And I have a couple of methods like:

```
protected fun setEngineValue(myEnum: MyEnum<Float>, value: Float): Boolean {}

protected fun setEngineValue(myEnum: MyEnum<Int>, value: Int): Boolean {}
```

I want to merge it into one function where the type of `value` is inferred from `myEnum`. I have done this in other languages like `Typescript` but I can not find a way to do it in Kotlin.

Something like:

```
protected fun setEngineValue(myEnum: MyEnum<*>, value: typeOf *): Boolean {

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be done by binding them to a generic:

```kotlin
protected fun <T> setEngineValue(myEnum: MyEnum<T>, value: T): Boolean {}
```

Though note that, use of generic type in place of primitives will box them.